In Looker Studio, can you label the breakdown dimension AS WELL AS the dimension itself?
Hopefully the image explains what I'm trying to do.
The dimensions are "B&S", "BC", etc. but each one is broken down into separate Years. I know that the Years will appear when you hover on the chart, but is there a way to have them appear on the x-axis, either above or below the Dimension labels?Looker Studio chart
